# Undelete Entity in WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, odata

I have a WCF-client consuming a OData service. At some point the user can delete an entity. I do this with the `DataServiceContext.DeleteObject(object entity)` method. So the Entity.State becomes Deleted.

The user has the possibility to undo the deletion. How can I make the state back to Modified?

Comment: I already tried to set the State via the Method `DataServiceContext.ChangeState(obj, EntityStates.Modified)` but this does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally achieved to do it by:

```
DataServiceContext.Detach(obj);
DataServiceContext.AttachTo("EntitySetName", obj);
```

This removed the deleted status from the object and added it as modified.

Answer (score 0):

A REST API is (or should be) stateless. You cannot undo something that was deleted. It's gone.

What you can do is not to delete things. Rather keep an IsDeleted flag in your data that you set to `true` and save when something is to be deleted and that you can set back to `false` when you want to undelete it. Obviously, all your queries and modifications need to take this flag into account.

Comment: I think I have to clearify my question. The change (deletion) is not transmitted to the service. I want to set the state of the entity as "not deleted", so that it isn't deleted on transmittion to the service.